How properly configure RestClient OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in Integration-Test
Hi Spring Security Community,
is there a good approach/ best practice for disabling the new OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in Integration-Tests, which has been integrated in this PR for Release 6.4.0.
Currently we override the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with a @Primary Component which overrides the default behavior of the OAuth2 client interceptor.
@TestConfiguration
public class OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptorTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor provideTestInterceptorForOutgoingRequests() throws IOException {
        var interceptorMock = Mockito.mock(OAuthClientCredentialsRequestInterceptor.class);
        when(interceptorMock.intercept(any(), any(), any()))
                .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                    HttpRequest request = invocation.getArgument(0);
                    byte[] body = invocation.getArgument(1);
                    ClientHttpRequestExecution execution = invocation.getArgument(2);
                    return execution.execute(request, body);
                });
        return interceptorMock;
    }
}

This approach works but feels not intended, because the whole interceptor will be replaced.
Should we follow to replace the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager with a No-Op OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager (like this approach here)?
I really like your work and hope you have a answer for my not so specific question :-)!

For the OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor class, there is a default implementation of ClientRegistrationIdResolver which is RequestAttributeClientRegistrationIdResolver. This requires you to provide the clientRegistrationId you would like to use for each request made by a RestClient through attributes, like so:
this.restClient.get()
    .uri(resourceUri)
    .attributes(clientRegistrationId("okta"))   
    .retrieve()
    .body(...)

In order to "disable" the interceptor, you can simply not provide a clientRegistrationId and the interceptor will pass on (skip processing) the request. You could do this by somehow conditionally including attributes(), but this might be challenging to do in your production code.
Another way to do this would to create a custom no-op resolver for your "mock" instance of OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor which will ignore the attributes(), like this:
@Bean
public RestClient restClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
    OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor =
            new OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor(authorizedClientManager);
    requestInterceptor.setClientRegistrationIdResolver((request) -> null);

    return RestClient.builder()
            .requestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
            .build();
}

Of course, you can directly publish a bean of type OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor but since your application ultimately needs a RestClient, I think just publishing a RestClient makes sense (as demonstrated in the example above and the RestClient Integration section of the reference).
